# How to end an endless loop of providing input in python 3.11

Tags: python-3.x, string, while-loop, terminal

I am making a terminal emulator with the ability to create, modify, read, an delete files.
The create, read, and delete functions all work correctly, but Im having an issue making the create function work to the point where I only need to call it once instead of calling once per line.

I tried making a while loop and attempting to add a hotkey to break out of the loop, but whenever I would test the hotkey idea, I wouldn't be able to actually run the rest of the program, as the script would get hung up on listening for the hotkey to be pressed.

The loop I had looked like this

```
while True:
        try:
            f = open(fileName, 'a')
            while running == True:
                f.write(input('Enter text here:\n')+'\n')
            f.close
            break
        except:
            print('\nFile does not exist')
            break
```

I would run it, and It would allow to enter lines of code, but I couldn't save and close the file after I put the amount of lines I wanted to.

Comment: Do note that `f.close` does nothing. You probably meant to write `f.close()`. That said, manually resource handling like that is ill-advise. You should consider using a context manager instead: `with open(fileName, 'a') as f:`

Answer (score 0):

One way I found, after looking at @Brian61354270 's comment was to put the whole chunk into a `with` context manager, all while still inside a `while` loop

Eventually I got this, which seems to work.

```
while True:
        with open(fileName, 'a') as f:
            try:
                f.write(input()+'\n')
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break
```

I don't really need the KeyboardInterrupt at all in the program, because unless I'm in the middle of editing a file, I have a built-in exit function that just calls `exit()`